# If the received value is "" ,we want to delete that particular property from object

Tags: javascript

For a given object if the input "value" of a property is "" , we want to delete that property from the object .

Ex

```
{
 "Speed": "59 MBPS",
 "latitude": "90.2",
 "longitude": ""
}
```

As per the example ,since the value of longitude is "" , this should get deleted from the object.
Please suggest a javascript code to achieve this .

Comment: use `filter` to get it out of the array

Comment: This is an object not an array.

Comment: To `delete` a key (or a property) from an object you can use, well, the `delete` keyword

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: `for (var propName in obj) { if (obj[propName] === "") { delete obj[propName];}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get keys from the Object. Then you can `filter` the properties `!==""` and then reduce it to form an `Object`.

Something like this:-

```js
let o = {
  "Speed": "59 MBPS",
  "latitude": "90.2",
  "longitude": "",
  "prop": ""
};

let res = Object.keys(o).filter(k => o[k] !== "").reduce((acc, cv) => {
  acc[cv] = o[cv];
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Or simply use `delete` like below:

```js
let o = { "Speed": "59 MBPS", "latitude": "90.2", "longitude": "" };

for (let key in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(key) && o[key] == "") {
        delete o[key];
    }
}

console.log(o);
```

Comment: You could also have found a dupe and posted that

Comment: Now I will keep to find dupes in for such questions before answering them :)

Comment: This in IMO cleaner: `for (var propName in obj) { 
    if (obj[propName] === "") {
      delete obj[propName];}}` instead of wasting time on getting the keys